# Expected Value for 2 Random Variables with Joint Probability Distribution

Tags: expected-value, density-function, joint-distribution

I have trouble with determining the domain for integration in the case of having a joint pdf when one variable depends on the other. There are two examples I don't quite understand, and hopefully, you can help me out.

**Example 1:** $ f(x,y)=2, 0\le x\le y \le 1$
In the solution, the expected values for $X$ and $Y$ $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ are given as:
$$E[X]=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} 2x \,dy \,dx$$
$$E[Y]=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{0} 2y \,dx \,dy$$
In the first case, we are using $1$ and $x$ for the inner integral. In the second case, I believe we are supposed to use $x$ and $1$ rather than $0$ and $1$(based on inequality). Am I wrong? I don't see why in the first case we chose $x$ rather than $0$ for the initial value while in the second case we chose $0$ over $x$ as an initial value.

**Example 2:(similar concept but applied to marginal pdf):**

Let $X$ and $Y$ have a joint pdf $f(x,y)=1, x\le y\le x+1, 0\le x\le1$
Then,
$$f_{X}(x)=\int_{x}^{x+1}1dy,0\le x\le1$$
$$\begin{equation}
  f_{Y}(y)=\begin{cases}
    \int_{0}^{y}1dx=y, & \text{$0\le y\le1$}.\\
    \int_{y-1}^{1}1dx=2-y, & \text{$1\le y\le2$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$
Why does here $f_{Y}(y)$ branches into 2 parts and why can't we simply say that $f_{Y}(y)=\int_{x}^{x+1}1dx$ ? (simillar to $f_{X}(x)$) . I do get that we need to get a function in terms of $y$ but all I am doing is just looking at the given inequality.

I ask these 2 questions together because I believe the issue comes from the same misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Sketch the domains of integration in the plane; that will make everything obvious.

Comment: Could you please correct your question title as it is missing at least one noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing (correctly)
$$\mathbb E[X]=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} 2x \,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dx$$
one skips intermediate steps:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} x f(x,y)\,\,\mathrm d(x,y)\tag{definition}\\
 &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} x\times2\times\mathbb I_{\underbrace{\{(x,y);\,0\le x\le y \le 1\}}_{\text{support set}}}(x,y) \,\,\mathrm d(x,y)\\
&= \int_{\underbrace{(0,1)^2}_{\text{max range}}} x\times2\times\mathbb I_{\{(x,y);\,0\le x\le y \le 1\}}(x,y) \,\,\mathrm d(x,y)\\
&= \int_0^1 2x \Big\{ \int_0^1 \mathbb I_{\underbrace{\{y;\,x\le y \le 1\}}_{\text{$y$ sliced support}}}(y)\,\mathrm dy \Big\} \,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_0^1 2x \Big\{\int_x^1 \,\mathrm dy\Big\} \,\mathrm dx
\end{align}
The same applies to $\mathbb E[Y]$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} y f(x,y)\,\,\mathrm d(x,y)\tag{definition}\\
 &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} y\times2\times\mathbb I_{\underbrace{\{(x,y);\,0\le x\le y \le 1\}}_{\text{support set}}}(x,y) \,\,\mathrm d(x,y)\\
&= \int_{\underbrace{(0,1)^2}_{\text{max range}}} y\times2\times\mathbb I_{\{(x,y);\,0\le x\le y \le 1\}}(x,y) \,\,\mathrm d(x,y)\\
&= \int_0^1 2y \Big\{ \int_0^1 \mathbb I_{\underbrace{\{x;\,0\le x\le y\}}_{\text{$x$ sliced support}}}(x)\,\mathrm dx \Big\} \,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_0^1 2y \Big\{\int_0^x \,\mathrm dx\Big\} \,\mathrm dy
\end{align}